# Matter.js Sprite Size

Tags: javascript, sprite, matter.js

I am making a physics simulation using matter.js.

My question is, is it possible to change the sprite size?  Or is that not possible using only matter.js?

This is what I have so far:

```
Bodies.circle(x, y, 46, {
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'images/stone.png'
      //Is there a 'width:' or 'height' property?  
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bodies.circle(x, y, 46, {
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'images/stone.png',
      xScale: 2,
      yScale: 2
    }
  }
});
```

Also see here in the [docs](http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_render.sprite.xScale).

Comment: It would be cool if there was a way to set the size exactly in pixels, or even better, to match the size of the bounding box of the shape, so we don't have to calculate that manually. Related issue: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/120